# WinForm ByteViewer Control equivalent in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, telerik

Is there any equivalent WPF control of [WinForm ByteViewer Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.byteviewer(v=vs.110).aspx) as below:

[image]

I'm trying to implement a tool similar with Wireshark. And I'm looking for WPF control to display binary data.

Comment: why does it have to be WPF ?

Comment: because I'm using WPF, and want to use MVVM with this control

Answer (score 2):

Try this, WPF HexaEditor Control;

NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPFHexaEditor/0.5.0

GitHub: https://github.com/abbaye/WPFHexEditorControl

**Features**

- Modify bytes
- Delete bytes
- Add bytes (soon)
- Save changes (work fine with file large file but when bytes as
  deleted of less than 500mg (for now)...)
- Selection with mouse/keyboard or property
- Most of property is Dependency Property. You can use binding :)
- Choose the number of byte per line to show
- Set position in code
- Unlimited Undo (no redo for now)
- Move in file with mouse wheel / or keyboard
- Modify mode (hexa / char)
- Finds methods (FindFirst, FindNext, FindAll, FindLast, FindSelection)
  and overlord for (string, byte[])
- Highlight byte with somes find methods
- Scollbar marker for selection start and byte finded (soon bookmark
  will be added)

Answer (score 0):

For WPF you can use my WPF HexEditor Usercontrol on GitHub/Nuget. A fully customisable WPF user control for editing file or stream as hexadecimal.

https://github.com/abbaye/WPFHexEditorControl

```
<!-- XAML -->
<Control:HexaEditor/>
<Control:HexaEditor Width="NaN" Height="NaN"/>
<Control:HexaEditor Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
<Control:HexaEditor FileName={Binding FileNamePath} Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
```

[image: Image1]